# Why when handling exceptions from multiprocess.Process KeyboardInterrupt exception can be catched only if you throw it yourself?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let's say I've got a bunch of Processes, I want to run those and check if they are OK:

```
procs = [fetcher_process, checker_process, publisher_process, manager_process]
try:
    for p in procs:
        p.run()
except Exception as e:
    print("Oopsie")
    exit()

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

Such a code works flawlassly, unless you hit Ctrl+C. Then you get unhandled `KeyboardInterrupt` in p.run() even though it is definitely handled in the try/except.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keddad/Documents/thevyshka-news-fetcher/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    p.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/keddad/Documents/thevyshka-news-fetcher/fetchuler.py", line 19, in fetch_news
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

But, if I create custom SIGINT handler which throws the same `KeyboardInterrupt`, like this:

```
def raise_keyboards_ex():
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, raise_keyboards_ex)
```

Then the try/except starts working as expected. So, why one `KeyboardInterrupt` is being caught here while other don't?

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` is intentionally *not* a subclass of `Exception`, specifically so that people don't accidentally catch it and therefore make their program unkillable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @jasonharper said, the reason why it wasn't catched was not some kind of magic - it is just because `KeyboardInterrupt` is not a subclass of `Exception`. The only reason it catched it now was that instead of rising `KeyboardInterrupt` I actually caused another exception:

```
try:
    for p in procs:
        p.run()
except Exception as e:
    print("Oopsie")
    print(e) # prints "raise_keyboards_ex() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given"
    exit()
```